# Need an example vue-router (vue 2.x) for a Layout.vue with other route based components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I cannot figure out how to set this up properly using `vue-router` with vue.js 2.x

I want App.vue to be a main site layout module which contains basic site level things like footer, logo, main nav, etc.

A route based architecture which will load components based on the route inside this App.vue

ie: `/things` to show list and `/things/:id` to show individual item

I'm using the webpack template from `vue-cli`

I'm confused about main.js vs. App.vue should I be moving the routes out of main.js into App.vue?

Can someone link to a simple hello world using layouts in vue-router?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Items from './components/Items'
import Item from './components/Item'
import Axios from 'axios'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios

const routers = new VueRouter([
  { path: '/items/:id', component: Item },
  { path: '/', component: Items }
])

// how to specify App.vue as a layout?
new Vue({
  routes
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Check my repo here https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/tree/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app

Take look into layouts directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

or spread operator

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    ...App
}).$mount('#app')
```

As I mentioned in comment, take look at the repo that I created https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/tree/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for except I'm getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matched' of undefined` when I load the page. If I remove `<router-view>` from `App.vue` the error goes away and I get the header and footer but no content.

Comment: Did you have defined the `#app` div into the App.vue or it's defined into html file, php or whatever?

Comment: yes `<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header-bar></header-bar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <footer-bar></footer-bar>
  </div>
</template>`

Comment: header and footer load if i remove `<router-view>`

Comment: Okay, so try to move that outside `.vue` file, so keep it in your main template file, blade or whatever

Comment: I have it also in `index.html`

Comment: Remove `#app` from App.vue and keep it only in html file

Comment: same error. if i remove `<router-view>` it still shows header/footer.

Comment: Oh I see now, you are passing arguments to VueRouter constructor in a bit wrong way - check how I did it here, and compare with your, and you will see issue https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/blob/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app/router.js#L12

Comment: It should be like this `const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{ path: '/items/:id', component: Item },
  { path: '/', component: Items }]
})`

Comment: i'm doing exact same thing you are. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a52df5dc3954614645f14d1f9b014ce4  and https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6405be0b6a3e5c0ef6f8073bfc7a909e

Comment: Hm, I think this line here could be issue maybe `import App from './App'` you forgot to set `.vue` extension.But not really sure, pretty strange error to em

Comment: If I load `<things>` inside App.vue it works. But that's not really what I want. I want to inject the component into App.vue based on the route. I see you have a `./views` directory layer which I am not needing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand - the `<router-view>` will handle all stuf about "injecting" components.Views in my structure are components that are attached to specific routes, you can call it and assign whatever component you want to specific route path.

Comment: you have this view component that calls `<my-component>` I don't have that.

Comment: Are you on skype? aettinger

Comment: Fixed it: `new Vue({
  router,
  ...App
}).$mount('#app')
` I had called it `routes` not `router`

Answer (score 1):

I had wrong property name:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  ...App
}).$mount('#app')
```

This fixes it. I had imported it as `routes` not `router`. Another way to fix would have been `{ router: routes }` but I renamed the file to `router` and now everything works.

Big thanks to @belmin for hoping on screenhero to try and help me fix it!